# Почему не запускается анимация?

Tags: javascript, html, css, анимация

Это должна была быть анимация шарика, катящегося по дороге, в зависимости от введённых параметров: vts(обозначены как numberv numbert numbers). Но она не запускается. Если нужны поеснения по коду-пишите.

```js
train.onclick = function() {
  let start = Date.now();
  var inputs = document.getElementById('numbers')
  var inputt = document.getElementById('numbert')

  var numbers = Number(input1.value);
  var numbert = Number(input2.value);

  var sum = 30 * numbers / numbert * 1000; //Это длина одного шага, для контролирования скорости
  let timer = setInterval(function() {
    let timePassed = Date.now() - start;

    train.style.left = sum + 'px';

    if (timePassed > 2000) clearInterval(timer);

  }, 30);
}
```

```css
#train {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

#road {
  height: 10px;
  width: 50px;
  background: #ba8dff;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<img id="train">

<h3>Расстояние</h3>
<input type='number' id='numbers' value="50" oninput="road.style.width = ${this.value}px;">px

<div id="road"></div>

<h3>Время</h3>
<input type='number' id='numbert' value="50">

<h3>Скорость</h3>
<input type='number' id='numberv' value="50">
```

Comment: а что значит 30numbers или numbert1000 ? где они в коде? почему решили что называть переменные с числа - это верно?

Comment: параметры  vts это numberv numbers numbert

Comment: input1 is not defined

Comment: вы бы привели корректный код для начала

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
train.onclick = function() {
  let start = Date.now();
  var inputs = document.getElementById('numbers')
  var inputt = document.getElementById('numbert')

  var numbers = Number(inputs.value);
  var numbert = Number(inputt.value);

  var sum = 0; // <--- Начальное значение суммы
  let delta = 1; // <-------- сюда надо вписать корректные данные и формулу из vts
  let timer = setInterval(function() {
    let timePassed = Date.now() - start;
    train.style.left = sum + 'px';
    sum += delta; // <------ прибавляем в интервали дельту   
  }, 30);
}
```

```css
#train {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

#road {
  height: 10px;
  width: 50px;
  background: #ba8dff;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<body>

  <img id="train">

  <h3>Расстояние</h3>
  <input type='number' id='numbers' value="2" oninput="road.style.width = ${this.value}px;">px

  <div id="road"></div>

  <h3>Время</h3>
  <input type='number' id='numbert' value="2">

  <h3>Скорость</h3>
  <input type='number' id='numberv' value="2">


</body>

</html>
```